# Docker containers disappear without trace

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04, Docker 19.03.12, and Compose 1.25.0.

I run several applications through my Docker compose file (example below). Recently, some containers (mainly Jackett but once Deluge) will completely disappear, they don't show with `docker ps -a`, and I can't access their logs because the container doesn't exist.

I don't really know how to go about diagnosing this because there doesn't seem to be any trail to follow.

**Jackett service entry**

```
  jackett:
    image: linuxserver/jackett
    container_name: jackett
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: service:vpn

    # depends_on:
    #   - vpn

    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_STORAGE}/jackett/config:/config

    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID}
      - PGID=${PGID}

    # networks:
    #   - traefik_proxy

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.jackett.entryPoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jackett.rule=Host(`jackett.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jackett.tls=true"
    
      ## HTTP Services
      - "traefik.http.routers.jackett.service=jackett"
      - "traefik.http.services.jackett.loadbalancer.server.port=9117"
    
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.jackett.middlewares=chain-auth@file"
```

Comment: Something deleted the container (e.g. `docker rm`). You're in a better position to figure out what process did that than we are.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I could start looking? I have no idea what could be specifically removing Jackett and leaving everything else

Comment: Docker doesn't delete a container unless you tell it to. I have no idea what you are running in your environment that may be doing this, and nothing provided in the question above provides any detail that would lead us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue appears to be `Ouroboros`. I was thinking what would have access to starting and stopping docker containers, and I had a look in the Ouroboros logs and found this:

```
2020-08-12 07:18:44 : INFO : dockerclient : jackett will be updated
2020-08-12 07:18:48 : ERROR : base : Job "Interval container update for unix://var/run/docker.sock (trigger: interval[0:05:00], next run at: 2020-08-12 07:23:01 UTC)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/containers/create?name=jackett
```

This looks like the problem to me